# Python function decorator error

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I tried to use function decorators, but in this example it dooesn't work for me, can you give me the solution ?

```
def multiply_by_three(f):
    def decorator():
        return f() * 3
return decorator

@multiply_by_three
def add(a, b):  
    return a + b

print(add(1,2)) # returns (1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

Interpreter prints error: "TypeError: decorator() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given"

Comment: It's telling the truth.  Your `decorator` function doesn't take any arguments, byt when you call `add(1,2)`, you are eventually calling `decorator(1,2)`, because this is what you return from your `multiply_by_three` method. Also, consider not calling it "decorator" because that will make it very confusing to discuss (since `multiply_by_three` is the actual decorator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a decorator, the function you return from the decorator replaces the old function. In other words, the `decorator` function in `multiply_by_three` replaces the `add` function.

This means that each functions signature's should match, including their arguments. However, in your code `add` takes two arguments while `decorator` takes none. You need to let `decorator` receive two arguments as well. You can do this easily by using [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs):

```
def multiply_by_three(f):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs) * 3
    return decorator
```

If you now decorate your function and run it, you can see it works:

```
@multiply_by_three
def add(a, b):  
    return a + b

print(add(1,2)) # 9
```